Align the labels at centre of the each bar block
I have a data like this
dput(FCXM_AA_sp)
structure(list(Specificity_uniqueaa = structure(1:54, levels = c("A3_D161", 
"A*30:01_W152", "B57_V97", "Cw5_K138", "Cw9_R91", "B13_L145", 
"A*11:02_K19", "B18_G30", "A2_H74", "B63_F4", "B44_V199", "Cw16_L193", 
"DR8_L74", "DQ4_D71", "A80_S31", "A80_E56", "A80_N74", "A80_K253", 
"A80_K255", "Cw1_K6", "Cw1_C99", "Cw1_M248", "Cw7_L194", "Cw7_M261", 
"Cw7_S273", "DR7_K14", "DR7_Q25", "DR7_L30", "DR10_E10", "DR10_R30", 
"DR10_V31", "DQ2_S28", "DQ2_S30", "DQ2_I37", "DQ2_L52", "DQB1*06:01_P3", 
"DQB1*06:01_L9", "DR4_H13", "DR4_H33", "DR4_Y96", "DR51_Q9", 
"DR51_Q191", "DR53_A11", "DR53_C13", "DR53_L18", "DR53_W25", 
"DR53_N26", "DR53_I28", "DR53_N41", "DR53_Q48", "DR53_Y81", "DR53_Q187", 
"DQ5_L14", "DQ5_S125"), class = "factor"), AA = structure(c(17L, 
2L, 5L, 14L, 15L, 4L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 12L, 
16L, 19L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 18L, 4L, 16L, 
15L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 
8L, 4L, 2L, 19L, 3L, 19L, 18L, 11L, 18L, 4L, 12L), levels = c("F", 
"W", "I", "L", "V", "A", "M", "C", "P", "G", "Y", "S", "H", "K", 
"R", "E", "D", "Q", "N"), class = "factor"), FCXM = c("Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative"), 
    FCXM_no = c(-1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
    -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
    -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
    -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L)), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = "data.frame")

I want the output like this

I want the labels should be at centre in the blocks of each bar.
I have used the code to get this desired output
ggplot(FCXM_AA_sp, aes(y = FCXM_no, x = AA, fill = FCXM)) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6, color= "white", size=0.5) +   # draw the bars
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Specificity_uniqueaa,"")),nudge_y=10,colour = "black", size = 4, hjust = 8.4, vjust = 1) + #angle=90
  scale_y_discrete() + # Labels
  scale_x_discrete() + # Labels
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="FCXM vs AA") +
  theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette

Please help to align the labels at centre of the each bar block.

In contrast to geom_bar which uses position="stack" by default a geom_text uses position="identity". Hence, to align the labels with the bars you have to use position_stack for geom_text too, and center the labels inside that bars add vjust=.5, i.e. use position = position_stack(vjust = .5) for geom_text (and get rid of all the unnecessary modifications via hjust= and nudge_y=).
Also note that I switched x and y to get rid of the coord_flip:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(FCXM_AA_sp, aes(x = FCXM_no, y = AA, fill = FCXM)) + # Fill column
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", width = .6,
    color = "white", size = 0.5
  ) + # draw the bars
  geom_text(
    aes(label = Specificity_uniqueaa),
    size = 8 / .pt,
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
    color = "white"
  ) +
  labs(title = "FCXM vs AA") +
  theme_tufte() + # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  ) + # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")



Hi Stefan, thanks for your solution. I want to ask if there is a way to edit the x-axis labels, like first, how to remove it? or secondary, how to supply user-defined x-axis labels from left to right like 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3.

A quick way to remove the x-axis labels would be to use + scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) (besides that you can also remove the labels via the theme, e.g. + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()). To customize you could pass a vector of your breaks= and labels=. But for your desired result you could do + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1), labels = abs) to get breaks at a distance of 1 and use abs to label with the absolute value.

Thanks, Stefan, it works. One last question. How I can switch positive first and negatives later in the graph?
